# Problems with creating subfolders in CodeIgniter 3 HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have a project that contains several subfolders, such as:

1. client/auth/login = model/view/controller
2. client/auth/signup = model/view/controller
3. admin/signin = model/view/controller

I set up my routes like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/signin/signin";
$route['admin/sigin'] = "admin/sigin/signin/index";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/sigin/signin/";
$route['client/auth'] = "auth/login/login";
```

These routes are not working, which shows CodeIgniter **404 error** page.

Comment: have you tried with index.php in url `http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/sigin`

Comment: yes, i tried it.. but it doesnt work...it shows **404 error**

Comment: I see you missing `$1` here `$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/sigin/signin/$1";`

Comment: i added **$1**..still its not working

Comment: Can you take a snap shot image of your modules folder.

Comment: May be try admin > controllers > signin > Controllername.php

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Can you share your modules directory structure like @Mr.ED asked for?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoJkQ.jpg   - here is the pic of my directory structure

Comment: `$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/sigin/signin/$1";` should be `$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/signin/signin/$1";` ? there is a missing n for the first signin

Comment: In fact ... you have 3 missing n's

Comment: I corrected my spelling..but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/signin/signin";
$route['admin/signin'] = "admin/signin/signin/index";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/signin/signin/$1";
$route['client/auth'] = "auth/login/login";
```

Fixed typo's above.
And I think your file structure is not correct. I use CI2, not sure how modules work in CI3. But the modules 'forgot_password' and 'signin' would be using the same models right? Why having them in separate folders/modules? This way when you make a change to the User model, you'll have to make the change in every User model in all modules (unless you don't need it in that cases, but still I wouldn't risk building my app like that)

```
- modules
    - Admin
        - controllers
            - user.php // Will have methods like signin(), add(), view(),...
    - Client
        - controllers
            - auth.php // Will have methods like signin(), signout(), ...
        - models // This will hold models you don't need in Admin module
                 // other models should be in the default models folder, so each module will be able to access them.
```

The routes would look like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/user/signin"; // admin module, user controller, signin method
$route['admin/signin'] = "admin/user/signin";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/content/$1"; // admin module, content controller, (:any) method (content being an example, I have it in my CMS project)
$route['client/auth'] = "client/auth/login"; // client module, auth controller, login method
```

Comment: thanks, for your suggestion..its really informative..thanks again....but the route which you have written its not working

Comment: I think that has to do with how your folder structure was set up.

Comment: i uploaded my folder structure snap shot,,I think my route set up is correct

Comment: Problem is CodeIgniter might not support your folder structure, can you post a screenshot of which files are in the controller folders?

Comment: here is the full structure of my module https://i.stack.imgur.com/RosRr.jpg

Comment: Yes well... I think the controllers you have should be methods of a controller like I added to my answer. I can think of some cases where you would want subfolders (submodules) in the module folder. But in CI2 that does not work either. Once I tried it with controllers and couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Are you using [this HMVC extension](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src)? I never used it before, but you might be able to contact them to get more info on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..In config file, I have added the following line of code;

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/'                   => '../modules/',
    APPPATH.'modules/admin/' => '../modules/admin/', 
    APPPATH.'modules/client/' => '../modules/client/', 
);
```

It works like a charm..:)